# Generating random division problems in python

Tags: python, math

I need to generate random division problems for an educational game that I am building. Generating random addition, subtraction, and multiplication problems is not too difficult. But I want my division problems to not have any remainders.

With addition, subtraction and multiplication, I could just do [random number] times or plus or subtract [random number].

It is not so easy if I want to do division problems. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: An example of what your are trying to achieve might make your problem a little clearer.

Comment: I don't think this is a "stackoverflow" question. However, can't you generate them the same way you do your multiplication questions? Just change the values you set for your question. This also works better if you want to limit the factors to a certain range.

Comment: if `a = b * c` and `b ≠ 0` then `a ÷ b = c`. So just generate random integers `b  ≠ 0` and `c`, compute `a` and you have your division problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x/y = z

y*z = x

Generate y and z as integers, then calculate x.

Answer (score 2):

1) Take any non-zero randomized Divisor (x).  // say 5

2) Take any randomized temporary Dividend (D).  // say 24

3) Calculate R = D % x; // => 4

4) return Dividend as (D -x ) // return 20

Now, your dividend will always be perfectly divisible by the divisor.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply generate the divisor and quotient randomly and then compute the dividend. Note that the divisor must be nonzero (thanks to @o11c's remind).

Comment: he can generate also a remainder

Comment: Constraint: both factors must be nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Vira has the right idea.
If you want to generate `a` and `b` such that `a = b * q + r` with `r=0`, the good way to do it is :

1. Generate `b` randomly
2. Generate `q` randomly
3. Compute `a = b * q`
4. Ask to compute the division : `a` divided by `b`. The answer is `q`.

Answer (score -1):

you can generate a number to be divided as [random number1]x[random number2]
. The problem will then be [random number1]x[random number2] divide by [random number1]

Comment: Asterisks are used for italics. You can escape them to avoid it: `\*`

Answer (score -2):

GZ0 has offered a great solution, one that is likely the most elegant. As an alternative, you could use the modulo operator, %.

```
if num1 % num2 == 0:
    return num1, num2
```

You can use that to generate a list of a hundred or a thousand pairs to use in your program.